# Magento2 how to define theme in my themes.js

Tags: magento2, grunt

What is the correct way to define theme in theme.js

> dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js

My theme in app/design is  Hose/Fit

```
<theme>: {
  area: '<area>',
  name: '<Vendor>/<theme>,
  locale: '<language>',
  files: [
    '<path_to_file1>', //path to root source file
    '<path_to_file2>'
  ],
dsl: 'less'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use file `dev/tools/grunt/configs/local-themes.js`, and define your theme as any other:

```
    fit: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Hose/Fit',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
```

The `files` array is a destinations of your generated styles eg `pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/styles-m.css`

Remember that grunt is only for development purposes, you won't need it in production enviroment.